# Threading with Tkinter, how to apply threading to a function without calling it with a button, Python, Threading, Tkinter, GUI

Tags: python, multithreading, tkinter

I am stuck with a problem, I have a server which receives a counter from a client each time a button is executed on the client. With this counter the server calculates a value "code", and this result must be compared to an input "e". If they are the same the GUI must display "Congratulations: You have been granted access!", if not "Your access has been denied".
So, the problem is that It looks like I need to use threading to execute this program, otherwise, it gets frozen, but I cant execute threading outside a button, when I do so, the GUI doesn't load. And when I call threading from the Button(how it is now) the comparison that I want it is done automatically, that means, I dont have to click on the Button to make the comparison, but I have to... Also, this comparison should be done as many times as I want, depending on the counter I receive...
So, is there any way to separate the Button that makes the comparison from threading and have my program the way I want it to be?

I am attaching the cliente code as well. I have tried to separate the functions into several ones, but I got similar problems.

```
#SERVER:
import socket
from argparse import _MutuallyExclusiveGroup
from tkinter import *
import hmac
import hashlib
import time
import threading
from threading import Thread

HOST='127.0.0.1'
PORT=6595

root = Tk()
root.title("Server")
root.geometry("300x200")
e = Entry(root, width=50, bg="white", fg="black")
e.pack()

#Code for the socket
server=socket.socket(socket.AF_INET,socket.SOCK_STREAM)
server.bind((HOST,PORT))
server.listen()


def myClick():
    communication_socket, address = server.accept()
    key = "800070FF00FF08012"
    key = bytes(key, 'utf-8')
    while True:
        counter=communication_socket.recv(1024) #Reception of the information from the client
        if not counter: break
        counter=counter.decode('utf-8') #Main algorithm
        msg = bytes(f'{counter}', 'utf-8') #Main algorithm
        digest = hmac.new(key, msg, "sha256").digest() #Main algorithm

        offset = digest[19] & 0xF
        code = digest[offset: offset + 4]
        code = int.from_bytes(code, "big") & 0x7FFFFFFF
        code = code % 1000000
        code = "{:06d}".format(code) #Result of the algorithm that uses the counter sent by the client

        key = key.replace(key, digest)  # Replacing the key used for the algorithm for each iteration
        #myLabel and Hash should be not displayed, I am doing it only for corroboration purposes
        myLabel.config(text=f"Message from client is {counter}") #Displaying the counter received
        Hash.config(text=code) #Displaying the result

        #This is the most important part
        input = e.get()  #COMPARING THE INPUT WITH THE VALUE(code) CALCULATED BY THE ALGORITHM
        if (code == input):
            result.config(text="Congratulations: You have been granted access!")
        else:
            result.config(text="Your access has been denied")


#This Button should be used only to compare the variable code to the variable input and display it #on the label "result"
myButton = Button(root,text="Compare Input to Code",command=threading.Thread(target=myClick).start())
myButton.pack()

myLabel=Label(root)
myLabel.pack()
Hash=Label(root)
Hash.pack()
result=Label(root)
result.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

```
CLIENT:
# Cliente code:
from argparse import _MutuallyExclusiveGroup
from ast import Delete
from tkinter import *
import hmac
import hashlib
import time
from turtle import width
from xml.dom.pulldom import END_DOCUMENT
import socket

HOST='127.0.0.1'
PORT=6595

#Code for the socket
cli=socket.socket(socket.AF_INET,socket.SOCK_STREAM)

root=Tk()
root.title("Client")
root.geometry("200x100")


cli.connect((HOST,PORT))
key="800070FF00FF08012"
key=bytes(key,'utf-8')
x=0
def button_click():  
    global x
    global key
    x +=1
    msg=bytes(f'{x}','utf-8')
    digest = hmac.new(key, msg,"sha256").digest()
    key=key.replace(key,digest)

    offset = digest[19] & 0xF
    code = digest[offset : offset + 4]
    code = int.from_bytes(code, "big") & 0x7FFFFFFF
    code = code % 1000000
    code="{:06d}".format(code)    

    myLabel.config(text=code)
    counter=str(x)
    cli.send(counter.encode('utf-8'))
    count.config(text=counter)
    

OTP=Button(root,text="Generate OTP",padx=20,pady=10,command=button_click)
OTP.pack()
myLabel=Label(root)
myLabel.pack()
count=Label(root)
count.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: You're starting the thread in the button declaration `command=threading.Thread(target=myClick).start()` It's supposed to be just a reference `command=threading.Thread(target=myClick).start`

Comment: Hi, thanks for your comment, Actually, I have tried that as well, but only works for the first comparison, for the second and subsequents it is done automatically. I expect to control the comparison for as many comparisons/iterations as I want